# Apple Watch Table Design?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there a way to do these color-side-bars:

[image: watchTable]
<sub>(source: [imageupload.co.uk](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/11/25/apple-watch-calendar-app-home-screen.jpg))</sub>

Without inserting Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WKInterfaceButton` and set its `background color`
otherwise Add a `WKInterfaceSeparator` and set its `color`

Answer (score 1):

Add a group with two subgroups. The second subgroup contains the labels:

[image]

The second subgroup needs alignment vertical:

[image]

Change the radius of all groups to 0:

[image]

Change the size properties of the first subgroup (to realize the coloured line):

[image]

Change the colour of the first subgroup:

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]